# Why isn't this function type-annotated correctly (error: Missing type parameters for generic type)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Is this function type-annotated correctly?

```
import subprocess
from os import PathLike
from typing import Union, Sequence, Any


def run(shell_command: Union[bytes, str, Sequence[Union[bytes, str, PathLike]]], **subprocess_run_kwargs: Any) -> int:
    return subprocess.run(shell_command, check=True, shell=True, **subprocess_run_kwargs).returncode
```

I'm guessing it's not, because I'm getting:

`he\other.py:6: error: Missing type parameters for generic type`

To get the same error, then save the above code in `other.py`, and then:

```
$ pip install mypy

$ mypy --strict other.py
```

Comment: This code is working for me (`Python 3.6.3`). Can you add the full error stacktrace to see which line exactly raises the error?

Comment: you get an error when you save this in a file, let's say other.py

and then:
```
$ pip install mypy

$ mypy --strict other.py
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PathLike` is a generic type, so you need to use it with a type parameter (`AnyStr` for example):

```
import subprocess
from os import PathLike
from typing import Union, Sequence, Any, AnyStr


def run(shell_command: Union[bytes, str, Sequence[Union[bytes, str, PathLike[AnyStr]]]], **subprocess_run_kwargs: Any) -> int:
    return subprocess.run(shell_command, check=True, shell=True, **subprocess_run_kwargs).returncode
```

Related issues:

- https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6112
- https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6128

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I didn't check this code at runtime. With some tricks it is possible to write a workaround:

```
import subprocess
from os import PathLike as BasePathLike
from typing import Union, Sequence, Any, AnyStr, TYPE_CHECKING
import abc


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    PathLike = BasePathLike
else:
    class FakeGenericMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
        def __getitem__(self, item):
            return self

    class PathLike(BasePathLike, metaclass=FakeGenericMeta):
        pass

def run(shell_command: Union[bytes, str, Sequence[Union[bytes, str, PathLike[AnyStr]]]], **subprocess_run_kwargs: Any) -> int:
    return subprocess.run(shell_command, check=True, shell=True, **subprocess_run_kwargs).returncode
```

Issues related to this workaround:

- [mypy: how to define a generic subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414066/mypy-how-to-define-a-generic-subclass)
- https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5264

Comment: I get `TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable` if I do this.

Comment: Updated my answer, now there is no errors both with `mypy` and at runtime.

Comment: Glad to help you. Yes, I think it brings more problems that mypy strict check solves.

Answer (score 19):

As described in sanyash's answer, `os.PathLike` is defined as a generic type. You can look at the [stub in the typeshed repo](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/5fdd6ad1a59d9a7e44979866b3b9acabfee64a90/stdlib/2and3/builtins.pyi#L1144). However, `os.PathLike` is only generic in the stub file, **the implementation importable from `os` is not**.

Not specifying the type var parameter (`path: PathLike`) leads to a mypy error. Specifying the type var parameter (`path: PathLike[Any]`) leads to a Python interpreter (runtime) error.

This exact issue has been raised in the mypy repo as [#5667](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5667). As a result [PR #5833](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/5833) extends the mypy documentation:

- https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runtime_troubles.html#using-classes-that-are-generic-in-stubs-but-not-at-runtime

The added section points out three ways to handle this:

1. Interpretation of the annotation by the Python interpreter (at runtime) can be disabled with a special `from __future__ import annotations` import, [see here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runtime_troubles.html#future-annotations-import-pep-563). This is planned to become the default in Python 3.10 and solves a bunch of annotation related issues.

   ```py
   from __future__ import annotations
   from os import PathLike
   import subprocess
   from typing import Any, Sequence, Union

   def run(shell_command: Union[bytes, str, Sequence[Union[bytes, str, PathLike[Any]]]], **subprocess_run_kwargs: Any) -> int:
        return subprocess.run(shell_command, check=True, shell=True, **subprocess_run_kwargs).returncode
   ```
2. Use `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` to supply different annotations depending on whether a type checker or the Python interpreter (runtime) interprets the file.

   ```py
   from os import PathLike
   import subprocess
   from typing import Any, Sequence, TYPE_CHECKING, Union

   if TYPE_CHECKING:
       BasePathLike = PathLike[Any]
   else:
       BasePathLike = PathLike

   def run(shell_command: Union[bytes, str, Sequence[Union[bytes, str, BasePathLike]]], **subprocess_run_kwargs: Any) -> int:
       return subprocess.run(shell_command, check=True, shell=True, **subprocess_run_kwargs).returncode
   ```
3. Supply the annotation as a string. The Python interpreter (runtime) will not interpret the annotation, but mypy picks up the proper meaning.

   ```py
   import subprocess
   from typing import Any, Sequence, Union

   def run(shell_command: Union[bytes, str, Sequence[Union[bytes, str, 'PathLike[Any]']]], **subprocess_run_kwargs: Any) -> int:
       return subprocess.run(shell_command, check=True, shell=True, **subprocess_run_kwargs).returncode
   ```

Comment: I stumbled upon the same issue, the second workaround works for me but now pylint complains about the Any import being unused. Is there a way to fix this without silencing pylint?

Comment: You can disable this particular message for this particular line https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#message-control. If support for understanding string annotations is added to pylint, this will not be necessary any more.

Comment: The documentation has moved, see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runtime_troubles.html#using-classes-that-are-generic-in-stubs-but-not-at-runtime now. For Python 3.7+, it seems like the recommended way is `from __future__ import annotations`.